# How to reduce the file size of a xml file that is created using java?

Tags: java, xml, size

I have to convert a text file with coordinates into a xml file. But the point of converting the text file into a xml file is so that the file size to be smaller. How can I reduce the size of my file?

```
public void writeXML() throws Exception
    {   
        ArrayList<Frame> frameList = new ArrayList<Frame>();    
        frameList = readFile();

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder;

        try
        {
            dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.newDocument();

            // append stuff                

            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();

            //transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);

            StreamResult console = new StreamResult(System.out);
            StreamResult file = new StreamResult(new File("file.xml"));

            //transformer.transform(source, console);
            transformer.transform(source, file);
            System.out.println("DONE");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }    
    }
```

Comment: You could zip the file. But "the point of converting the text file into a xml file is so that the file size to be smaller" is a flawed promise. XML adds markup overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But the point of converting the text file into a xml file is so that the file size to be smaller.

That is probably not achievable.  XML is less dense than a typical text representation because properly designed XML adds a significant amount of "markup" to the file.

A file consisting of coordinates in an appropriately designed text form (e.g. CSV) will take less space than the same coordinates expressed in XML.

If you want "denser" files than a custom text format:

- consider compressing the text file, or
- consider using a binary representation instead of text.

---

If you are fixed on the idea of using XML, then the best way to reduce file size will be to compress it.  Given that XML has a lot of redundancy in it (e.g. the markup), you should get significant compression.